# Which one will be better multiple small queries or one single big query for the MySQL usages and performance?

Tags: mysql, database

I have thousands of row data and I want to do something like this shown below in the code.

```
   (SELECT Username, AddTime
     FROM Table1
     WHERE Type = 3 AND AddTime >= '2019-07-11 13:30:00' AND Username = 'Test1'
     LIMIT 1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT Username, AddTime
     FROM Table1
     WHERE Type = 3 AND AddTime >= '2019-07-11 13:40:00' AND Username = 'Test2'
     LIMIT 1);
```

I want the suggestion which one will be better whether to use one big query like shown above using `UNION ALL` or should I use multiple small query like shown below for thousands of times?

If I use UNION ALL then there will be thousands of UNION ALL to be used in one single query.

```
SELECT Username, AddTime
     FROM Table1
     WHERE Type = 3 AND AddTime >= '2019-07-11 13:30:00' AND Username = 'Test1'
     LIMIT 1
```

**NOTE:**

- I have exactly 140k row data.
- I tried with around 100 rows in one single query using UNION ALL it almost takes around 50 seconds to query the data.

Comment: If any query of a single 100 row table takes 50 seconds then there are some other **very serious issues** with your database

Comment: Also, what exactly is your required output

Comment: limit 1 will give you 1 non-determinate record where the conditions are met, is that what you want?

Comment: 'if i use UNION ALL then there will be thousands of UNION ALL'  - why would that be, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: SELECT Username, AddTime
     FROM Table1
     WHERE Type = 3 AND AddTime >= '2019-07-11 13:30:00' AND Username = 'Test1'
     LIMIT 1

for Every user has their different action time. so i want to get the data for every user whose action time is close or near to the AddTime from the db.

Comment: for example. 
if user a clicks a button on toolbar at X time and then after few seconds or minutes he makes an api call from the page he went by clicking on toolbar. 
so i have log data of click time on toolbar and the api call time in the db. i want to compare the time different between the click time and the api call time added in DB

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually it is for 100 UNION ALL in one single query

Comment: (SELECT Username, "2019-07-12 17:23:16" AS ClickTime, AddTime
     FROM Table1
     WHERE Type = 3 AND AddTime >= '2019-07-12 17:23:16' AND Username = 'sag***'
     LIMIT 1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT Username, "2019-07-12 16:35:49" AS ClickTime, AddTime
     FROM Table1
     WHERE Type = 3 AND AddTime >= '2019-07-12 16:35:49' AND Username = 'Rag****'
     LIMIT 1);

i want to have a result like this

sag***      "2019-07-12 17:23:16"     "2019-07-12 17:25:16"
Rag****    "2019-07-12 16:35:49"     "2019-07-12 16:39:49"

for thousands of records

Comment: Even if you want only one value (which is the case with your LIMIT 1) , the query will "retrieve" all. The LIMIT clause is done only after. So the query get all result, and THEN send you back only one. IAs the two query seems to be the same, I would suggest to change to get AND (Username = 'Test1' OR Username = 'Test2')

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this instead:

```
SELECT tbl1.Username, tbl1.AddTime, min(tbl2.AddTime)
FROM Table1 tbl1
INNER JOIN Table1 tbl2 
ON tbl1.userName = tbl2.userName AND tbl1.type = tbl2.type and tbl2.addTime >= tbl1.addTime
WHERE type = 3  
AND tbl1.addTime >= '2019-07-11 13:30:00'
AND userName in ('Test1', 'Test2') 
AND tbl1.addTime <= DATE_ADD(tbl1.addTime, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)  --optional but prob want to do something like this to limit result set
GROUP by tbl1.Username, tbl1.AddTime
```

Note that I am not at my work machine, so I have not tested it. 
Also, given the number of records you mentioned, you probably have some indexes for this table to speed up the query. The best would probably have a covering index on addTime, type and userName but play with it to optimize your query .

Comment: Thanks. but the condition for addTime you write for every user will have different addTime associated with it. its like one to one relation with username and addTime. but the condition you write seems to be one AddTime for multiple users.

Comment: How about inserting the userName and the addTime pairs into a temp table and then join the temp table in the statement above instead of using parameters? So, part of the where clause in the statement above would now look like this tbl1.addTime >= tmp.addTime and tbl1.userName = tmp.username.

Comment: you mean i write temp table in db?

Comment: okay i get it i create one temporary table up till the connection is available. once we close the connection the temporary table will be removed itself right?

Comment: Yes insert into temp table in DB, so that then you can join to it afterwards.

Comment: Yes, once the connection is closed the temp table will automatically removed. Or you can drop it yourself once you are done if you want more control.

Comment: but i don't have access to create temp table XD

Comment: Maybe you can talk to the dB admin to give you the ability to create them? Otherwise, you are pretty much set at querying one result at a time. It will work , but it will be linear performance (if getting 1 result takes 1s, then getting 100 will take 100 * 1 s). Talk to your dB admin and see what he suggests.

Comment: got it thanks.
btw is it possible to create my own another db and then connect these 2 db to get the result?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Is it advisable? Not really. You would have to import data and keep it in synch, not to mention creating all the code to access and merge the results from the two DBs. I would just talk to the dB people, explain the situation and see if they have an alternate solution.